# parent() method in the security api for firebase

Tags: javascript, authorization, firebase, firebase-security

I would like to set the following rule in firebase security.
To authorize write, I would like to make sure that the auth.user_id is the same as RulesDataSnapshot called "user_id" under the parent of the current branch

In order to do so, I tried writing the following write_rule:

```
".write": "auth.user_id == (data.parent().child('user_id').val())"
```

Firebase security API has a section on parent() method. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rulesdatasnapshot/parent.html

I used the parent() method as shown in the example. However, I recieve an error " No such method 'parent' "

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is data in your example?

Comment: data refers to the current branch that you are writing the rule in. For example the the the parent folder called "ParentFolder" has two sub folders (children) called "ChildFolder1" and "ChildFolder2" and then some of its own data (think files). So i am writing the rule inside ChildFolder1. ChildFolder1 is what data refers to. so data.parent() should refer to ParentFolder. I would like to refer to the file called "user_id" inside ParentFolder (outside the child folders) and compare to auth.user_id.   

Hope this clears something up.

Comment: Sorry!  .parent() is a brand new feature and we accidentally deployed the docs for it before the actual implementation. :-) I'll try to get a server deploy scheduled for tomorrow, after which point you'll be able to use .parent() and I'll update this question.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.parent() is a brand new feature and we accidentally deployed the docs for it before the actual implementation. :-)  We just deployed the updated server code, so .parent() should work fine now.  Give it another go!